# Repair wiring of ATR6550 Condensor Microphone with 3.5mm Jack

Tags: connector, battery-operated, microphone, condenser-microphone

I own a **ATR6550** **Condensor Shotgun Microphone** in which at some point before going to my university i forgot a battery at it leaked causing corrosion on connections in battery Section and some broke out.
The Spring on -ve battery terminal also broke and the wire Marked with Number **E203950** was connected to the -ve terminal.
There is a wire i am not sure where to connent.
Please ask if you need any extra information.

> Connections on +ve terminal of battery are fine.

[image: Mic Diagram]

[image]

Comment: I'll let others speak for themselves, but I think you haven't provided enough information for definitive answers. If this were me, I'd be pulling out my binocular microscope and providing detailed photographs as well as a much more comprehensive set of pictures of the overall system. I also have a spool of military grade 19-conductor silver plated copper wire for just these repair purposes. I don't mess around. Is this device worth all the trouble you are likely to go do in repairing it? (That's another question I ask myself -- and I face these questions 3-4 times a year it seems.)

Comment: Hey, @jonk I understand that information might not be complete, I will try to add more and circuit diagrams if available .Yes, I want to repair it because this is the only microphone I have ,also I bought this with the first small income i got from working for gig for someone. Thanks for heads up , i'll update it with more info.

Comment: You will need some soldering skills as well as just plain and simple mechanical skills. Here's an [image of the microphone *system*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPjsC.jpg) I found on the web. That alone is worth gold. It provides a lot of information about the total system you are dealing with. You can then drill in with added photos to provide detailed context of what is going on, where precisely the damage is located, and what needs to be addressed. Anyone seriously wanting to offer help will want to know as much as you can provide about the details and circumstances. Goes a long way.

Comment: @jonk Yes, I followed your suggestion and found a video on youtube of the person solving some other issue with same model and both wires are connected to -ve terminal. Thank you very much ! I got it. Should i remove this question ?

Comment: If you feel you already have enough, then I'd suggest one of two actions: (1) remove the post; or, better yet, (2) give us an answer about what you learned and what you did to repair it! Then select your own answer! It might help others if you do that. It's not a bad thing to have a good question here, with some good results in the end. Someone else may find it very helpful. And it is perfectly okay to write your own answer and select it.

Comment: @jonk Sure,i will share my answer .Someone might find this helpful.

Comment: That's great!! Please help others with what you learn! It's how this place works, in part. And I think it's great that you have a problem that motivates you to work out a solution in the end. I'm sure others will appreciate your time and thoughts offered to them, though you may not always realize how many people you helped in the end. It's just the right thing to do. Helping others, I mean. Best wishes with what's ahead for you and I'm so glad you found something helpful, already! (+1 for the right attitude and all. And again best wishes!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @jonk I browsed around and found a Youtube Video by KrauseHouse where he is sorting out his broken microphone.This is how you do the connection for -Ve Terminal

> Both the wire i knew about and the other wire I marked as coming from
> or going towards microphone are to be connected to -ve Terminal.

[image: Microphone Design]
[image: -Ve Terminal of Microphone]

I finally did it and its working great !
Soldered both wires on the end metal plate and made a new spring out of Paper Clips I had with me.Punched a hole in and soldered that spring on back of the plate.

[image: Solution]